# How to filter a python dataframe by the maximum grouped Value of a specific column

Tags: python, filter, max

So I am try to get a df that shows the latest Price based on a grouped dataframe. Below is a df of 9 records to help explain.

```
         Country   ISO Month  Price
0        Germany   DE  201311 7.99     
1        Germany   DE  201310 8.99
2        Germany   DE  201309 6.99
3   United States  US  201310 4.99
4   United States  US  201309 11.99
5   United States  US  201308 2.99
7         France   FR  201311 7.99
8         France   FR  201310 1.99
9         France   FR  201309 1.50
```

I want the df to return the price that relates to the maximum Month. Like to return the below view:

```
         Country   ISO Month  Price
0        Germany   DE  201311 7.99     
1   United States  US  201310 4.99
2         France   FR  201311 7.99
```

I tried doing a groupby with a max() and could return the maximum month by doing the below

```
df.groupby(['Country','ISO'])['Month'].max().reset_index()
```

but the above dropped the Price out that relates to that month, and if included the 'Price' in the groupby it obviously then return all the 3 values per country as they are different values.

Sorry I couldn't find the answer i was exactly looking for after 2 hours on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, using the sort and first in a groupby seemed to get the result I need.

```
df.sort('Month', ascending=False).groupby(['Country','ISO'], as_index=False).first()
```

would return:

```
         Country   ISO Month  Price
0        Germany   DE  201311 7.99     
1   United States  US  201310 4.99
2         France   FR  201311 7.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data stored in mysql?
If the data is in a list like[(0,"Ger..","DE",201311,7.99),(....] then your goal could be achived by this code:

```
the_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[3], reverse=True)[:3]
```

returns the data from first three largest month.

Comment: hi Luyi, the data is being imported from a excel file actually and so is in a spreadsheet tabular format with headers.  the data actually has more columns and countries and even a week field. so i need it to dynamically just return the 'price' for each combo when filtered on the maximum month of each combo. thus for the US it was actually October i needed to return and the others were  November.

Comment: I have more of an MS access background. In access I would have just done a query on the data with the required fields, with GroupBy selected and a criteria of max of Month